# How to access the VMware filesystem

Tags: vmware-workstation

I run VMware workstation with Ubuntu on it on my Windows XP box. Is there a way to access the Linux filesystem inside the Virtual machine from Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [VMware Workstation 5.5 Disk Mount Utility](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html)

The most recent versions of VMWare have that built in; go to your virtual machine settings, hard disk, utilities, and "Map virtual disk"

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set it up as a file server and access it that way?  You could also probably use telnet to remote into the ubuntu machine.

Comment: telnet needs to die

Answer (score 0):

Sharing folders is another solution to do it while having the VM running.